# How can I navigate between views/screens by dragging sideways (swipe gesture)?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I want the user to change the displayed window by dragging it sideways. It shouldn't matter where exactly on the screen is his cursor (so only the dragging action matter) I draw a little representation of what I have in mind. I want the user to see the 2nd screen coming after the cursor, even retracting when he moves his cursor back to the right (basically following his cursor). This action should be both ways: from main window to 2nd window AND from 2nd window back to main window
How would you approach this?

EDIT:
Picture 1; The user places his cursor on point A and clicks. While holding click he drags it across the green arrow.

Picture2; This picture represents and intermediate state when the "slide" is still in progress (you can see the "Statistics" screen still hasn't fully taken over the initial screen)

Picture3; Represents the final state; after the user got at the end of the (imaginary) green arrow. The Statistics screen is now fully displayed and the user can read the information that is on it.

The opposite of what happened now should be allowed (dragging from left to right in order to go back to the initial screen)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "change the displayed window"? Do you mean to change the position or the appereance of that one window or do you mean to swap the displayed window with another one so that the new one then is the displayed window? Also, by "main window" and "2nd window", do you actually mean main and second screen? Please clarify these things, otherwise it is very hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I wanted to swap the displayed window with another one (views in XML I suppose) . In the drawing I used "screen" and but I was still referring to windows (views) not to the actual user's monitor screen

Comment: Hum, it is still very unclear what you are trying to achieve. My best guess is that you whant to move some `UIElement` from one of your `Window`s to another one. Maybe some ([minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) xaml code of what you already have or two sketches (before and after) would be helpfull to clarify.

Comment: I edited with more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply a translate transform to your content.

The following example shows how to drag the content (or the image of the content). For simplicity, the example only shows how to swipe from right to left. It also doesn't show how to implement a history to navigate back. You would need a `Queue` to store the next pages and a `Stack` for the previous pages (based on the swipe direction).
Although the below example does it, I don't recommend to use controls directly to handle pages and their navigation. Instead create page data models and render the controls using a `DataTemplate` for each page model.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public object CurrentPage
  {
    get => (object)GetValue(CurrentPageProperty);
    set => SetValue(CurrentPageProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentPageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "CurrentPage", 
    typeof(object), 
    typeof(MainWindow), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  private StackPanel DraggableContent { get; }

  // Accept swipe after 25% swipe delta 
  // based on the max possible swipe width (a displayed page).
  // Note that the 'PageHost' will host two pages (their image) 
  // during the swipe action.
  private double SwipeAcceptDragThreshold 
    => this.PageHost.ActualWidth / 2 * 0.25;

  private bool IsSwiping { get; set; }
  private double HorizontalDragStart { get; set; }
  private UserControl PreviousPage { get; set; }
  private UserControl NextPage { get; set; }

  /* Page controls */
  private UserControl GreenPage { get; }
  private UserControl OrangePage { get; }
  private UserControl BluePage { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.GreenPage = new PageControl() { Background = Brushes.Green };
    this.OrangePage = new PageControl() { Background = Brushes.Orange };
    this.BluePage = new GreenPage() { Background = Brushes.Blue };

    this.CurrentPage = this.GreenPage;
    this.NextPage = this.OrangePage;

    this.DraggableContent = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
  }

  protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    this.HorizontalDragStart = e.GetPosition(this).X;
  }

  protected override void OnPreviewMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnPreviewMouseMove(e);
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
    {
      return;
    }

    double dragDelta = e.GetPosition(this).X - this.HorizontalDragStart;
    if (!this.IsSwiping)
    {
      bool isSwipeRightToLeft = dragDelta < HorizontalDragStart;
      UserControl swipeInPage = null;
      UserControl swipeOutPage = null;
      if (isSwipeRightToLeft)
      {
        if (this.NextPage == null)
        {
          return;
        }
        swipeInPage = this.NextPage;
        swipeOutPage = this.CurrentPage as UserControl;
        this.PreviousPage = this.CurrentPage as UserControl;
      }

      this.IsSwiping = true;

      /* Create an image of the content that will be dragged, using VisualBrush */

      swipeInPage.Height = this.PageHost.ActualHeight;
      swipeInPage.Width = this.PageHost.ActualWidth;
      swipeOutPage.Height = this.PageHost.ActualHeight;
      swipeOutPage.Width = this.PageHost.ActualWidth;

      this.CurrentPage = null;

      // Prepare the snapshot
      this.DraggableContent.Children.Add(swipeOutPage);
      this.DraggableContent.Children.Add(swipeInPage);

      // To improve performance, the user will only drag a snapshot
      // of the pages. The snapshot is painted on an empty Grid
      // using a VisualBrush.
      this.CurrentPage = new Grid()
      {
        Background = new VisualBrush(DraggableContent),
        Width = this.PageHost.ActualWidth * 2 // Host two pages
      };
    }

    this.TranslateTransform.X = dragDelta;
  }

  protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
    if (this.IsSwiping)
    {
      this.IsSwiping = false;

      double dragDelta = Math.Abs(e.GetPosition(this).X - this.HorizontalDragStart);
      bool isDragAccepted = dragDelta > this.SwipeAcceptDragThreshold;

      // Disconnect page controls from the visual tree
      this.DraggableContent.Children.Clear();
      this.CurrentPage = isDragAccepted
        ? NextPage
        : this.PreviousPage;
      this.TranslateTransform.X = 0;

      // TODO::Generate and set next page or null if last page reached      
      this.NextPage = this.BluePage;
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>

  <!-- Allow content to exceed the Window -->
  <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PageHost"
                      Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=CurrentPage}">
      <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="TranslateTransform" />
      </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
    </ContentPresenter>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

**PageControl.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl>
  <Grid Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Background}" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I get the following 2 errors : that the method `SwipeTest` must have a return type , and that `MainWindow.DraggableContent cannot be assigned to -- it is readonly`

Comment: Now it worksm but when I try to come back to the initial screen I get an Unhandled Exception `System.ArgumentException: 'Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget.'` I get this at line 96 in MainWindow.xml.cs

Comment: I have not implemented it for the other direction. I stated this in my answer. Also fetching the next page from a e.g. Stack or previous page from a e.g. Queue is not implemented. The answer was meant to give you a raw pattern or foundation that you can work with. This answer was not meant to implement the complete control for you.

Comment: To avoid this error in general, make sure that you have called `DraggableContent.Children.Clear()` to remove the elements from the visual tree. This is because every instance can only be once part of the visual tree.